# Wordpress says page "not found" if includes trailing slash in URL?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

For every page on this subdomain, if there is a trailing slash it always says page not found, the page only loads correctly without the slash at the end,
eg it doesn't work : abc.com/us/ + redirects to abc.com/us/:
it does work abc.com/us

Every other subdomain in the multisite works correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file,

Add the following .htaccess code to fix the trailing slash issue.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$ $1
```

The above code will remove trailing slash (/) from the URL except the root.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's a multisite, this subdomain doesn't work correctly but all the others do, is it still the same method you mentioned?

Comment: @tommybc Kindly update your question with multisite.